# Why stdin of parent process still accepts inputs after closing stdin file descriptor from a forked child process?

Tags: python, linux

`fork(2)` manual page on the Linux system I'm running says the following:

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the  child  refers  to  the  same  open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two  file  descriptors  share  open  file  status flags, file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SET‐SIG in fcntl(2)).

And Python Documentation mentions

> `_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`.

Of course, `_exit` won't call cleanup handlers, the problem is that, if you look at this code for instance:

```
newpid = os.fork()
if newpid == 0:
    os.close(0)
else:
    time.sleep(.25)
    input()
```

The parent process still accepts inputs from stdin despite the fact the child process closes stdin. That's good and here's the code reversed:

```
newpid = os.fork()
if newpid == 0:
    input()
else:
    time.sleep(.25)
    os.close(0)
```

Now, it's the opposite, this time the parent process that closes stdin not the child. And this raises `EOFError` for the `input()` call in the child process.

This looks like when the [child] process writes/modifies the parent's file descriptors, it does not affect the [parent]. That is, the child process gets newer file descriptions.

Then why call `_exit` as Python Docs states to prevent invoking cleanup handlers if operations performed by the child process does not affect the parent process? Let's take a look at `_EXIT(2)` man page:

> The function `_exit() terminates the calling process "immediately". Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed; any children of the process are inherited by process 1, init, and the process's parent is sent a` SIGCHLD`  signal.
>
> The function `_exit()` is like `exit(3)`, but does not call any functions registered with atexit(3) or on_exit(3). Open stdio(3) streams are not flushed. On the other hand, `_exit()` does close open file descriptors, and this may cause an unknown delay, waiting for pending output to finish.

`fork()` manual page doesn't mention that the cleanup handlers of the child process are inherited from the parent. How does this affect the parent in any way? In other words, why not just let the child process clean up after itself and why not?

Comment: `EOFError` is not due to `os.close(0)`. You get it immediately, even if you use `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: It also doesn't happen if stdin is redirected to a pipe or file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running this from a shell within a terminal.

The shell launches the Python process in a new process group and uses `tcsetpgrp()` to set it as the foreground process group on the TTY.

Once the parent Python process terminates, the shell reclaims control of the terminal (it sets itself as the foreground process group). The shell does not know the forked child from Python is still running.

When a process which is not part of the foreground process group tries to read from the terminal, it normally receives a `SIGTTIN` signal. However, in this case, the process group has been orphaned because its leader has terminated, thus the child process gets an `EIO` error from `read()` on the TTY. Python treats this as `EOFError`.

Comment: The error happens before the pareent process terminates. Put a longer `time.sleep` and you'll see `EOFError` immediately, before the parent exits.

Comment: Also, if you change it to `print(input())` you'll see that it successfully reads the input after reporting the error.

Comment: @Barmar That is not the behavior I observe on my Linux machine.

Comment: @Barmar OP is on Linux.

Comment: Oh, I got an error, but I had to press an extra return after getting the shell prompt.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly, you see the error when the parent process exits and then you provide input to the terminal which the child process could potentially read. (Assuming the shell doesn't mask off SIGTTIN, which is possible, but shouldn't be the default. Most shells mask off SIGTTOU for convenience, though.)

Comment: @Barmar which Linux are u using? The error doesn't show up immediately, you have to type something into the shell first.

Comment: Debian, not sure the specific release.

Comment: @ephemient I tried to override `SIGTTIN` handler in Python. Why the handler doesn't get called?

Comment: @direprobs Oh, I actually need to adjust my answer a bit. `SIGTTIN` happens if the process group is backgrounded, but in this case your child is now part of an *orphaned* process group, which means reading from the console results in `EIO`, which Python translates that to an `EOFError`.

Comment: @ephemient  `sys.stdin.readline()` raises `OSError` exception instead of `EOFError`. `OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error` . That's great. Thank you